# get form fields except button with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am using a form in IE11 and try to use this workaround (https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/811930/ie11-crash-when-clearing-multiple-input-fields-with-jquery) to clear the form and also avoid the bug of crashing the browser .

See the workaround section of the above link. I try to use the code there. I edited the call of the function like so

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#clearFormSetTimeout').click(function(){
        clearFields(0, $("#myFormId :input"));
    });
})
```

And it works.

The only problem is that, in my form, I also have a button like

```
<input type="button" onClick="doSomethingCool();" value="Press Me">
```

that its values also gets null.

How do I avoid this? Clear all the fields of the form, but not the button.

What part do I have to edit? The call , or the function? And how?

I am new to JQuery.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clearFields(0, $("#myFormId :input").not('input[type="button"]'));
```

Answer (score 1):

change the jQuery to below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#clearFormSetTimeout').click(function(){
        clearFields(0, $("#myFormId input:not([type=button])"));
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the button with jQuery selectors

```
clearFields(0, $("#myFormId :not(input[type='button'])"));
```

Answer (score 0):

To clear form fields better to use trigger

```
$("#myFormId").trigger("reset");
```

it will reset your form