# Reset form except one input enclosed in DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this to reset a form when a visitor refreshes the page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  resetForms();
});
function resetForms() {
  document.getElementById('configurator-form').reset();
}
```

Inputs are radio, select, text. There is one input within (div class="snap") that I need to exclude from the reset. How can I do this?

Can I use:

```
.not('.snap input')
```

Somewhere? I guess to do this I would need to target the inputs and not the whole form? Fields have default values, so I don't think I want to use 'removeAttr', though I could be wrong?

*EDIT*

I know it's similar to another question, but I cannot get the accepted answer to work. It's suggested that the form value be taken, then the form is reset, then the value is put back into the form. I've tried with this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  var snap = $(".snap input").val();
  resetForms();
  $(".snap input").val(snap);
});
function resetForms() {
  document.getElementById('configurator-form').reset(); 
}
```

...But it hasn't restored the value of the ".snap input" field. It's worth noting that the snap field has a random name and ID, so I can't use getElementById for example. Thanks for your patience, as you can probably tell I'm new to JQuery.

*EDIT 2*

Ok, resetForms was throwing an error "not defined". This version seems to work perfectly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var snap = $(".snap").html();
  $('#configurator-form')[0].reset();
  $(".snap").html(snap);
});
```

Comment: I would modify your `resetForm()` function and make it reset each input field individually except the one you want to keep instead of reseting the entire form

Comment: I would like to have posted a simple answer, leveraging `jQuery`, but this question was marked as a duplicate before I could do so.  That question doesn't mention `jQuery`, so I posted [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34916946/4342563) using "vanilla" js.  If you are ok with using `jQuery`, the same approach would be simplified as I stated there.  It's [trivial to shim most of the core `jQuery` methods nowadays](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/), or [use a reduced set](http://evanhahn.com/doing-without-jquery/), but if there's interest I'll add a `jQuery` version to that answer.

Comment: Actually I came across [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20814408/4342563) to a similar question which is explicitly requesting a `jQuery` based answer.  That question happens to be addressing an issue with IE11, but the accepted answer shows how to do almost exactly what you were looking for I believe.  There's no point re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I need to digest your solution - as mentioned I'm relatively inexperienced with JS / JQuery so it'll take time for me to test. The answer relating to IE11 clears input values from the form, but I need to keep the default values.

Comment: If it's just a single input, why not simply temporarily copy value to a hidden field and then restore it after reset?

Comment: @user2265915 Are there multiple inputs nested under the `<div class="snap">`?  Do you want to exclude all of them from being reset?  Please post some markup that is representative of the section you wish to manipulate?

Comment: @user2265915 [`form.reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) will reset input elements to their [`defaultValue`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#dom-input-defaultvalue) property value.  You can specify the `value` attribute in the `input`'s markup, which becomes the `defaultValue` property value, *or* you can set it at any time using js: `inputElement.defaultValue = "new default value"`.  For checkbox this would be `defaultChecked` and for the `option`s under a `select` it is `defaultSelected`.

Answer (score 0):

You're approach should work.

The only mistake you have is the selector,

Your JS should look like this:
(without the white space in the selector)

```
function resetForms() {
var value = $("input.snap").val();
  document.getElementById('configurator-form').reset();
   $("input.snap").val(value);
}
```

[working fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/a3L6verz/1/)